# Death Penalty for Desecrating God's Name?

Tags: history, gentiles, capital-punishment, chilul-kidush-hashem

In light of some of the recent embarrassing criminal incidents involving visibly religious Jews in the United States, it made me think of something I had read once ( or vaguely remember reading ) that there were cases of Jews who committed certain highly visible ( but not capital offense ) crimes against non-Jews during the middle ages and where then executed by the Jewish community due to the hillul hashem involved.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about or the incident / cases I may have read about?  It's very vague and fuzzy in my memory.

Comment: I doubt that. A Sanhedrin would be necessary to execute someone and there was no Sanhedrin in the Middle Ages.

Comment: @Daniel There have always been ways of executing without executing - like locking someone up without food or water...

Comment: That isn't executing without executing. That's executing.

Comment: @Daniel That's not true. A Sanhedrin is only needed to mete out the special 4 punishments for the special capital crimes.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree that there is a difference between the two scenarios; but I just don't think it's likely that any Jewish court would take it upon themselves to "execute but not execute" someone. We have four methods of putting someone to death and this kind of seems like inventing a fifth.

Comment: @Daniel I was responding directly to your first comment. Any Beit Din can kill anyone directly if they want. ShA CM 2.

Comment: Robert are you thinking of this case? https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%91